# Deployment Group and Environment in Azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

I want to understand the difference between environment and deployment group in Azure Devops.

And when should I use one and not the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deployment Groups were the "old way" to do rolling deployment across multiple VMs. The new way is to use environments with the 'rolling' strategy from yaml.

My recommendation would be to let Deployment Groups lie and invest in Environments and YAML.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-group-phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: so, decline the depoyment group and focus on Environnement .?

Comment: Yups. That's the way forward.

Comment: It's difficult to understand Environnement ?

Comment: Docs are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops it isn't much different.